# init(coder:) has not been implemented in swift

Tags: swift

I have this class file for accepting card payments

```
import UIKit
class PaymentViewController: UIViewController , PTKViewDelegate {

    var card : STPCard
    var PaymentView : PTKView
    var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    init(PaymentView : PTKView , button : UIButton, card : STPCard) {
        self.PaymentView = PaymentView
        self.button = button
        self.card = card
        super.init()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

When I build it, it works fine, but when I execute it (run it) on my actual device , I get

```
fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I know because the fatalError line is doing it, but why do I have to do a required init and why is it not just happy with an init.

Comment: the actual method throws you a _fatal error_... I'm not sure what you really expected from a `fatalError()` line – you have got exactly what that line should do: a _fatal error_ exception. you can avoid such exception by implementing the method's body.

Comment: Yes I know Holex, but I am not sure why a REQUIRED is needed and what I should put it in.

Comment: maybe, calling the super class...? like e.g. `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`? oh, wait! that was not a question.

Comment: the `required` keyword indicates you, you have to override that method in your subset of the class.

Answer (score 20):

Based on the Inheritance Hierarchy you have setup. `PaymentViewController` will inherit 3 init methods. 
`UIViewController` provides `init(nibName:bundle)` as its designated initializer. 
`UIViewController` also conforms to `NSCoding` which is where the `required init(coder:)` comes from. 
`UIViewController` also inherits from `NSObject` which provides a basic `init()` method.

[image: UIViewController inherited init methods diagram]

The problem you are having stems from `init(coder:` being called when the ViewController is instantiated from a .xib or storyboard. This method is called to un-archive the .xib/storyboard objects.

From the Documentation:

> iOS initializes the new view controller by calling its initWithCoder: method instead.

You should be calling the superclass designated initializer in your `init` method, which is `init(nibName:bundle)` Note: it is fine for both of those parameters to be nil. Also your `init(coder:)` override should call `super.init(coder:)`

Comment: `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }`

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and calling super in `required init...` only says that properties `self.property_name ...` not initialized at `super.init` call.

Comment: @StanRedoute you'll want to read up on the initialize rules in swift. Short story at the end of any init method you'll need to have provided default values for all your stored properties. (this can be a little tricky in swift when using storyboards/init(coder:)) You'll probably want to make them `lazy var` so they can be computed after init time, or use Implicitly unwrapped optionals to tell the compiler you'll set them later. Docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

Answer (score 11):

A simple workaround will do:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and calling super in `required init...` only says that properties `self.property_name ...` not initialized at `super.init` call.